# Irreducible Polynomial in the field of rational functions

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and let $t$ be a variable. Let $L = F(t) = {a(t)/b(t)| a(t), b(t) ∈ F[t], b(t)≠  0}$.

I want to prove that the polynomial $f(x) = x^p − t$ as a polynomial in $L[x]$ , where $p$ is prime, is irreducible. So, a polynomial is irreducible if it cannot be factored into nontrivial polynomials over the same field, so does it suffice to show $f$ has no roots in $L$ somehow?

Comment: Read about the Einsenstein criteria

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment: Since $L$ is a field of fractions, its enough to check irreducibility over the ring $F[t][x]$. You can try Eisenstein criteria.

Comment: Ahh how to show there exist prime $p$ such that it divides $t$ but $p^2$ does not though? Can I just take $p = t$?

Comment: Read the Eisenstein criteria for an integral domain and apply it to $F[t]$ and yes $t$ is a prime in the ring $F[t]$.